# How do I use a property path passed to an Ember Component?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to do something like this

```
App.FooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    propertyPath: '',

    data: []
});
```

And in foo-component.hbs (this obviously doesn't work):

```
{{#each item in data}}
    <li>{{propertyPath}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I would use the component as follows:

```
{{foo-component data=content propertyPath='name'}}
```

where content is a collection of objects, each with a 'name' property.

I've tried to do it within the component by using a computed property and binding to that:

```
itemNames: function() {
    var propertyPath = 'data.@each.' + this.get('propertyPath');
    return this.get(propertyPath);
}.property(???)
```

But that has the problem of how to set the dependent key so the property is recomputed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
items: Ember.computed.map('data', function(dataObject) {
    return {
        name: dataObject.name,
        otherProp: dataObject.otherProp
    };
}).property('data.@each.{name, otherProp}')
```

You declare a computed property that maps the objects in `data` to some other objects. In your function, you can just return an object with the properties you need (I used `name` and `otherProp`). Then, to make sure that the property watches the `name` and `otherProp` properties on every object, I override the dependent keys with the `.property()` call. (By default, `Ember.computed.map` will call `.property('data.@each')` for you.)

Then, in your template:

```
{{#each items}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

EDIT:

The dynamic property name is a little weird. One way you could do it is to declare a computed property on the class at creation time.

```
init: function() {
    var propertyPath = this.get('propertyPath');

    this.reopen({
        propertyPathUpdater: function() {
            this.notifyPropertyChange('data');
        }.observes('data.@each.' + propertyPath)
    });
}
```

Depending on how your values update, you might have to mess with it a little, but hopefully you get the idea. The idea being that Ember doesn't like dynamic properties. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I'm not sure how this works when  the strings 'name' and/or 'otherProp' are passed in property paths from the component. I just tried calling 'property' on the relevant object property in 'init' but that doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason the dynamic property name completely slipped my mind. I do something similar to that in my code, it's it's a bit weird. Give me a minute to think about it.